# Inconveniente con el comando python manage.py makemigrations o python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien agradezco su amable colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente en Python al tratar de activar el entorno de PostgreSQL dentro de Visual Studio Code:

Estoy  trabajando con Python y PostgreSQL  pero en la consola tanto del Visual Studio Code o en la del cmd de Windows o Power Shell también del Windows al momento de querer trabajar lo siguiente:

Ya sea python manage.py makemigrations   o python manage.py runserver, me muestra lo siguiente en la consola:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\tasks\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Task(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql\tasks\models.py", line 7, in Task
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=TRUE)
                                                 ^^^^
NameError: name 'TRUE' is not defined. Did you mean: 'True'?
```

Igual me pasa cuando trabajo con python manage.py runserver

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Atentamente

Hernán Martínez

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y adjuntar el contenido de tu archivo models.py?

Comment: El error es muy claro, te dice que `TRUE` no existe, y que uses `True` en la linea 7 de models.py   `created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`